# C# calculate decimal

Tags: c#

I simply want to calculate a price by doing a simple sum. For example:

```
float HourPay = 18.30
int MinutesWorked = 125

minutesWorked \ 60 * HourPay = 38,124999999
```

I got these values in a C# function and am running into 2 problems:

```
private decimal CalculatePrice(int minutes)
{
    float test = minutes / 60 * setting.HourPay
    return;
}
```

The problems are, `test` returns 36.6 which is not correct and is rounded off to 1 decimal.

I want the correct answer that parses it to a decimal and rounds it to 2 decimals.

Comment: There are tons of duplicate questions.. Start reading http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: @SonerGönül i did read and a lot but after 60min i gave up. Sorry for not being able for searching as good.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you are starting with dividing two integers, which results in another integer:

```
float test = minutes / 60;
```

Note that `test` get's `2`, because all decimals are cut off if two integers are divided. So the calculation is actually right:

```
2 * 18.3 = 36.6
```

`test` should be `2.083...`. The solution is to cast your integers to floats first:

```
private decimal CalculatePrice(int minutes)
{
    float test = (float)minutes / 60.0f * setting.HourPay;
    return;
}
```

Then your division does not ignore the decimals and the result will be what you exprected. You can also leave out the explicit cast of `minutes`:

```
float test = minutes / 60.0f * setting.HourPay;
```

This is valid as long as the constant (`60.0f`) is marked as float, because integers that get divided by floats are implictly casted to integers. However, the first approach is probably easier to read.

Answer (score 9):

`minutesWorked` is an integer and so is `60`. So `minutesWorked / 60` -> `125 / 60` -> `2` rather than what you would expect it to be (`2.083333`).

if you just change it to

```
float test = minutes / 60.0 * setting.HourPay;
```

it should work as you expect.

I should add, it makes me cringe a little bit that you're using float for HourPay. Since that is essentially money (technically $/hr) decimal might be a better choice, especially since you're moving to decimal later in the process (as the result of your function)

Answer (score 1):

just try:

```
float test = minutes / 60.0 * setting.HourPay
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope this will help.

```
int minutesWorked  = 125;
float hourPay = 18.30F;
float item = (minutesWorked / 60.0F) * hourPay;
```

As per your code when minutesWorked get divide by 60 ( which is integer literal ) it give answer in integer so it return 2.

When you do 60.0 it will return answer as float and then get multiplied to hourpay.